# How to groupby and do addition with only those columns that are grouped

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following dataframe: I want to group by probeset column and get a single value for each phchp subject by adding up the data with the same probeset values

```
       Probeset  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3
0    1554784_at    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1    1554784_at    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2     212983_at    0.244668    0.032524    0.113343
3     212983_at    0.022178    0.013750    0.011871
4  1566643_a_at    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
       Probeset  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3
0    1554784_at    0           0           0
1    1554784_at    0           0           0 
2     212983_at    0.244668    0.046274    0.125214
3     212983_at    0.244668    0.046274    0.125214      
4  1566643_a_at    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528
```

I've tried the following to no success, it does not group correctly:

```
for x in df_out:
    if 'phchp' in x:
        df_out[x] = df_out.groupby(['Probeset'])[x].sum()
```

Comment: @ALollz I suppose it doesn't matter as long as the value is consistent for each row.  I'll update the proposed answer.

Comment: you can use `df_out.groupby('Probset').sum()` to get the groups and sums. It won't have the repeated rows though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` + `transform`, then assign back to the DataFrame.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Probeset').transform('sum')
df[df1.columns] = df1
```

---

```
print(df)

       Probeset  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3
0    1554784_at    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1    1554784_at    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2     212983_at    0.266846    0.046274    0.125214
3     212983_at    0.266846    0.046274    0.125214
4  1566643_a_at    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528
```

---

Your loop also wasn't too far off, you just needed to use `transform`. With `transform`, the result of the groupby aggregation is broadcast to all rows belonging to that group, so it will align with the DataFrame index. Without `transform`, the groupby result has an index based on the group keys, so simple assignment back to the DataFrame won't align, given you have a RangeIndex. The small change needed is:

```
for x in df:
    if 'phchp' in x:
        df[x] = df.groupby('Probeset')[x].transform('sum')
```

And for clarity, here is the difference in the groupby results with and without transform.

```
# Index is unique values of `'phchp367v3'`
df.groupby('Probeset')['phchp367v3'].sum()
#Probeset
#1554784_at      0.000000
#1566643_a_at    0.046528
#212983_at       0.250428
#Name: phchp367v3, dtype: float64


# Index is the same as the original DataFrame
df.groupby('Probeset')['phchp367v3'].transform('sum')
#0    0.000000
#1    0.000000
#2    0.250428
#3    0.250428
#4    0.046528
#Name: phchp367v3, dtype: float64
```